# How to know what last affected my reputation?

Tags: support

Seems like I should be able to figure this out on my own ... yet here I am :)

Example, I returned from lunch to find my reputation went up 35 points.  Cool!  However, I'd like to know specifically which questions/answers of mine got notched up (or down) during that period.

Is there an easy way to determine this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it by clicking the "envelope" and selecting the reputation tab and click on 'today'.

I don't know why this is different than the reputation tab on the user id page.

Comment: Thank you!  Looks like I haven't sufficiently explored that page.

Comment: You're welcome! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

I also just found the [reputation audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation).

Check out *your own* audit [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/reputation) (you must be logged in).

The questions are listed by ID and you can create the URL by id number: using rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/{**put question id number here**}/

Comment: Whoa, that is cool.  I'm not that obsessed with my reputation though...........yet :)

Comment: *yet* `:)` [ ](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Another way which may be more or less useful, is to click on your name, then the "reputation" tab. On the graph, drag to highlight only the most recent data point, this will display exactly the relevant information, even if it didn't happen that day.